# What's the proper syntax of mapping/filtering a data-stream element to convert its data type?

Tags: ios, json, swift, combine, urlsession

**Scenario:** Data stream that contains an item that has changed from an `Int` to `String` type causing the JSON parser to crash.

**Result:** Subscriber 'sink' crashed with data type not matching the original receiving type via JSON parser.

**Goal:** to convert the `Int` values to `String` to have a consistent stream for a successful parsing.

Here's a snippet of the data stream that has caused the crash:

```json
...
{
  "city": "אלון שבות",
  "sickCount": 124,
  "actualSick": 15,
  "verifiedLast7Days": " 11-14 ",
  "testLast7Days": 699,
  "patientDiffPopulationForTenThousands": 47
},
{
  "city": "סייד (שבט)",
  "sickCount": " קטן מ-15 ",
  "actualSick": " קטן מ-15 ",
  "verifiedLast7Days": "  0  ",
  "testLast7Days": 17,
  "patientDiffPopulationForTenThousands": 4
},
...
```

Here's the error via console:

> CodingKeys(stringValue: "sickCount", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Int but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Here's the code:

```swift
func getData() {
    let str = "https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/gov/Israel"
    let url = URL(string: str)!
    let remoteDataPublisher = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
        .map(\.data)
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .decode(type: IsraelDataElement.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
    
    remoteDataPublisher
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
            switch completion {
            case .finished:
                print("{IsraelModel} Publisher Finished")
            case let .failure(anError):
                Swift.print("\nIsrael - Received error: #function", anError)
            }
        }, receiveValue: { someData in
            self.add_UUID(origData: someData)
            print(someData)
        }).store(in: &cancellables)
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen when the value is a `String`? Or do you want to parse `sickCount` when it's an `Int` as a `String` always?

Comment: I want a single type (either Int or String).  But the original data has BOTH.  So It's easier to handle one type for processing.  The String type has Hebrew stating 'Less than 15' or whatever.  I can process that if the parsing can complete without errors.   Also, I would like to know how to further use the 'map' function to alter data-in-stream.   It's a 'black box' now.

Comment: Can you show what you want `IsraelDataElement` to be? Regardless, I think the right approach here is to manually decode the type and handle the different values as you want, e.g. try to decode String, failing that decode as Int and convert to String. I don't think I fully get what you mean by data-in-stream. Do you want to manually change value of type `Data`?

Comment: The data stream is not 'clean'.  There's a couple of items (columns in table format) that switch from Int to String data types.    It starts off as a JSON INT (so my data model has the INT) then it changes to a JSON STRING which crashes the .decode as stated.  I want to check & convert the INT (in a map of the 'producer') to STRING prior to .decoded JSON parsing so I can have a clean output for the subscriber.  BTW: This is a good exercise to be able to massage the data via stream prior to the subscriber.  I can play with the result once the subscriber received the data.  Now it breaks.

Comment: Ok, so my suggestion is to "clean" the data by manually decoding your type (by implementing `init(from: Decoder) throws` of `Decodable`. This is unrelated to Combine, `.decode` would just work in the Decodable is cleaning the data

Comment: I was hoping to use either filter or map within the stream to do the cleansing.  That would give the 'producer' more power; rather than to collect the result and try to repair.  Both methods are 'black boxes'; it's difficult to observe via the debugger.

Comment: I'm not sure which part you consider a black box (everything is a black box at some level of abstraction). You have `Data` values coming from upstream. What would you do with that variable outside of Combine? Do you have some function `(Data) -> Data` that "cleans" it - if so, use `.map` with that function. Alternatively, `.decode` transforms `Data` to the type you specify. But what is this type? Does it have a `String` for that property? Then you need to decode it as such. Maybe i'm not understanding what the issue is

Comment: I can use .decode a value for either INT or STRING.  But not both on the SAME value.  I could use JSON serialization without mapping to objects and do the long way to parse my data.  I suppose I could run two passes, one to filter for INT and the other for the STRING and normalize both into a common STRING and merge into one data set.  Seems a bit much.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure if what I was suggesting in comments wasn't clear, so here's an example of what I had in mind.

If the object you're trying to decode is:

```
struct IsraelDataElement {
  let city: String
  let sickCount: String,
  let actualSick: String,
  let verifiedLast7Days: String,
  let testLast7Days: Int,
  let patientDiffPopulationForTenThousands: Int
}
```

then you can manually decode it, converting renegade `Int`s to `String`s:

```
extension IsraelDataElement: Decodable {
   private enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
      case city, sickCount, actualSick, verifiedLast7Days //... etc
   }
   init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
      let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

      self.city = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .city)
      do {
         self.sickCount = try String(container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .sickCount))
      } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
         self.sickCount try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .sickCount)
      }
      // and so on for other properties
   } 
}
```

Then, no further changes are needed in your Combine chain.

Comment: Interesting. I had merely a passing thought about this.  I'll play with it.  Note: there's a lot of 'dirty' data like this floating about in cyberspace.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Swift strongly typed so it will not coerce the types for you.  If you genuinely mean for the types to be heterogenous then idiomatically you should use an enum to represent that this thing is either an Int or String.  This is the only way you can actually round trip the data and preserver the type.  For instance:

```
struct Element: Decodable {
  let city: String
  let sickCount: Either<String, Int>
  let actualSick: Either<String, Int>
  let verifiedLast7Days: String
  let testLast7Days: Int
  let patientDiffPopulationForTenThousands: Int
}

enum Either<Left: Decodable, Right: Decodable>: Decodable {
    case left(Left)
    case right(Right)

  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
    if let x = try? container.decode(Left.self) {
      self = .left(x)
    } else if let x = try? container.decode(Right.self) {
      self = .right(x)
    } else {
      throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(Self.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for \(String(describing:Self.self))"))
    }
  }
}
```

If this is just a case of your backend developers being sloppy then convert the type yourself and you can do so generically so you can easily fix their data problems everywhere in your app:

```
struct Element: Decodable {
  let city: String
  let sickCount: Int
  let actualSick: Int

  enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
    case city, sickCount, actualSick
  }

  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

    self.city = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .city)
    self.sickCount = try container.decodeAndCoerce(to: Int.self, from: String.self, conversion: Int.init(_:), forKey: .sickCount)
    self.actualSick = try container.decodeAndCoerce(to: Int.self, from: String.self, conversion: Int.init(_:), forKey: .actualSick)
  }
}

extension KeyedDecodingContainer {
  func decodeAndCoerce<Target: Decodable, Source: Decodable>(to: Target.Type, from: Source.Type, conversion: @escaping (Source) -> Target?, forKey key: Key) throws -> Target {
    guard let value = (try? decode(Target.self, forKey: key)) ?? ((try? decode(Source.self, forKey: key)).flatMap(conversion)) else {
      throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(Target.self,  DecodingError.Context(codingPath: codingPath, debugDescription: "Expected \(String(describing: Target.self))"))
    }
    return value
  }
}
```

Aren't generics fun?